# ¿Cómo mostrar un menú para distintos usuarios?

Tags: php, html, css

Quiero que cuando le de clic al botón de login de un menu aparezca la pantalla de login, que la persona escriba su usuario y contraseña en caso de ser correcta le redireccione al menu pero con nuevas opciones.

Para poner en contexto, tengo un menu que es el index y uso un archivo php llamado "menu.php" para modificar su estilo con lo siguiente `header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8", true);` en este archivo se encuentra la opción para esconder los elementos de una lista, seguí este consejo para hacerlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771551/how-to-hide-a-li-item-in-html-and-make-it-not-occupy-any-space.

index.html

```
      <li><a href="html/login.html">Login</a></li>
      <li class="hide"><a href="#">Consulta 1</a></li>
      <li class="hide"><a href="#">Consulta 2</a></li>
      <li class="hide"><a href="#">Consulta 3</a></li>
      <li class="hide"><a href="#">Consulta 4</a></li>
```

Y tengo un "login.html" que usa un css diferente llamado "login.css", para poder extraer la contraseña y usuario uso el método POST y después lo envió a "main.php" para que modifique la propiedad del selector "hide".

login.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action = "../php/main.php" method ="post">
  <section class="form-login">
    <h5>Login BobaDent</h5>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="usuario" value="" placeholder="Usuario">
    <input class="controls" type="password" name="contrasena" value="" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input href= "../index.html" class="buttons" type="submit" name="" value="Ingresar">
  </section>
</form>
```

El problema es que cuando coloco `$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];` en "main.php "deja de funcionar el estilo de debajo.

main.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8", true);
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
?>
body {
     background: red;
}
.hide{
   display:none;  
}
```

Me podrían ayudar por favor, tienen alguna mejor solución o saben porque sucede, soy nuevo con css, php y html espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Quizás debas clarificar un poco más la pregunta, pero: con HTML puedes crear la estructura. Con CSS puedes dar formato y diseño a esa estructura. Y con PHP programas del lado del servidor lo que le llegará al usuario. Creo que el planteo de desarrollo tiene cosas mezcladas. Si quieres mostrar cierto CSS puedes añadirlo condicionalmente con PHP (añadiendo el HTML que lo inserta)

Comment: no se entiende el contexto. Tomate tu tiempo y explícalo mejor

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué significa ”*después lo envió a "main.php" para que modifique el atributo*”? ¿Un atributo de una etiqueta HTML? ¿Qué etiqueta HTML? ¿Y qué significa "*El problema es que cuando quiero extraer los datos desde "main.php" deja de funcionar el estilo de debajo*"? ¿Qué datos quieres extraer? ¿Lo del usuario que ha iniciado sesión? Por favor, explica un poco mejor lo que deseas y si no conoces el término técnico de algo pon entre paréntesis una breve descripción de a qué te refieres. Explica qué es lo que esperas que ocurra y qué ocurre (mal) en realidad.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Lo edite y trate de explicar mejor mi problema, gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

justo tenia ese problema hace poco, lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear un sistema de rol en tu base de datos, y dependiendo que rol tenga (por ejemplo si es administrador que tenga una opcion llamada agregar producto y si es usuario que no tenga esa opcion) una vez haces eso en el principio de tu html tienes que colocar un condicional asi,
`<?php  session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){ ?>`

eso hara que cuando no se haya iniciado sesion coloque tu header en la manera sin iniciar sesion, y al final de todo añade esto

`<?php      }else{ $user = $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>`

aqui es cuando se inicia sesion y ahi podras cambiar las cosas para hacer que aparezcan puedes usar el codigo
`<?php if($user['id_cargo'] === 1) { ?>`

con eso se verifica si tiene un cargo 1 en micaso el 1 es administrador y si un administrador entra le apareceria un apartado distinto que otros, no se si me hago entender pero puedo ayudarte escribeme si eso

Comment: Gracias, lo intentare @kian 14.